# Lottery Analysis

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am doing a kind of simulation of lottery analysis through Python.
I've tried several methods but it didn't work well.
Here is my code:

```
from random import choice

activator = True
while activator:
    numbers_letters = [5, 4, 7, 9, 0, 'A', 'S', 'H']
    prize_winner = []

    for i in range (0, 4):
        selected = choice(numbers_letters)
        prize_winner.append(selected)

    my_tickets = {5, 'S'}

    if print(my_tickets.issubset(prize_winner)) == True:
        print("You win the prize!")
        activator = False
    else:
        count = 0
        count += 1
        continue

print(f"Trying attempt : {count}")
```

My last attempt came out with an infinite output with True/False, I know it is due to the while loop which did not escape well, but i have no idea how to edit it. I have been thinking about it for an afternoon, hope somebody can help me

Comment: The correct if is `if my_tickets.issubset(prize_winner):`, use `print` when you want to see something in the console

Comment: The print statement will print the result to the console so you are never actually comparing if the result is EQUAL to True in your if statement. That results in your infinite loop of prints. 

remove the print and it will then be an equivalent check.

Comment: owhhh, it is worked! Thanks buddy